# StreamingQueryException: Error while List shards

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-kinesis

I have a Kinesis data Stream whose records I want to insert it in the AWS redshift with using AWS Glue.I created crawlers to bring source table and target table .They are working fine with .

The code works when I save the records on S3 instead of Redshift .But When using Target as Redshift I get error.

However I keep getting error

"StreamingQueryException: Error while List shards"

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, Row
import datetime
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Kinesis Stream
dataframe_KinesisStream_node1 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
   database="dev",
   table_name="ventilators_table_kinesis",
   additional_options={"startingPosition": "earliest", "inferSchema": "false"},
   transformation_ctx="dataframe_KinesisStream_node1",
)


def processBatch(data_frame, batchId):
   if data_frame.count() > 0:
       KinesisStream_node1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(
           data_frame, glueContext, "from_data_frame"
       )
       # Script generated for node ApplyMapping
       ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
           frame=KinesisStream_node1,
           mappings=[
               ("ventilatorid", "int", "ventilatorid", "int"),
               ("eventtime", "string", "eventtime", "string"),
               ("serialnumber", "string", "serialnumber", "string"),
               ("pressurecontrol", "int", "pressurecontrol", "int"),
               ("o2stats", "int", "o2stats", "int"),
               ("minutevolume", "int", "minutevolume", "int"),
               ("manufacturer", "string", "manufacturer", "string"),
           ],
           transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
       )

       # Script generated for node Redshift Cluster
       RedshiftCluster_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
           frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
           database="dev",
           table_name="dev_projectlightspeed_ventilators_table",
           redshift_tmp_dir=args["TempDir"],
           transformation_ctx="RedshiftCluster_node3",
       )


glueContext.forEachBatch(
   frame=dataframe_KinesisStream_node1,
   batch_function=processBatch,
   options={
       "windowSize": "5 seconds",
       "checkpointLocation": args["TempDir"] + "/" + args["JOB_NAME"] + "/checkpoint/",
   },
)
job.commit()
```

PLease help !!

Answer (score 1):

Faced this similar error saying `StreamingQueryException: Error while List shards` while working with glue streaming job with S3 as output. As the error message indicates, the problem turned out regarding missing Kinesis permissions (to read the shards) in the IAM role of that job.

Giving the proper kinesis permissions worked for me.

But since your job works fine with S3 output but causes issue with Redshift, check that the job role has proper permissions for both redshift and kinesis.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, but it turns out it was a different problem. I am connecting AWS Glue to a Kinesis Stream in another account. All the permissions were setup correctly to allow cross account account and I was still getting this same error: `StreamingQueryException: Error while List shards`. Eventually I found some obscure message in the Glue logs:

```
'roleSessionName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 64
```

Glue was creating this `roleSessionName` based on the name of the firehose and appending a UUID. This was exceeding this limit. To solve I needed to create a new Firehose with a shorter name.